# Is Bootstrap 3 js included in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a bit new to Rails, but it seems amazing.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3's CSS components fine, but I'm not seeing where the JS is included. I checked my application.js file and there is no line for Bootstrap.

Does Rails 4 include Twiiter Bootstrap 3's JS, or only its CSS?

If it does not include the JS, do I just google for a gem and add that?

How can I tell if Rails has Bootstrap's JS - since there is no line for it in application.js?

Comment: My gemfile has "gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.0.0.rc'" but no entry for js

Comment: Solved - looks like I just needed to add "//= require bootstrap" to my application.js file. Found the answer on the gem's github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, bootstrap is not included with Rails.

When you put the line

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.0.0.rc'
```

Bootstrap is pulled into your app, and then you correctly included it your asset pipeline by putting `//= require bootstrap` in your application.js file.